# Get LONGTEXT from MariaDB to Oracle via DB Link

Tags: oracle, mariadb, oracle12c, dblink

My goal is to copy table containing `LONGTEXT` from MariaDB(10.1.26 64bit) to Oracle(12.1.0.1.0 64bit)

This is my `initCCS.ora` file:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=CCS
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=INFO
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME=/path/to/libodbc/libodbc.so
HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE=LOCAL
HS_NLS_NCHAR=UCS2
HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
set ODBCINI=/path/to/odbc/ini/odbc.ini
```

This is part of `odbc.ini` for CCS:

```
[CCS]
Driver = /path/to/lib/libmaodbc.so
server = mariadb.server.loc
database = db_name
CHARSET = UTF8
```

This is the table I'm trying to copy (I've simplified it to contain only 2 columns):

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|    Column    | Mariadb type | Oracle type |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| ID           | INTEGER      | INTEGER     |
| LONG_CONTENT | LONGTEXT     | CLOB        |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

`LONG_CONTENT` column contains huge strings (more than 32k symbols).

When I try to copy table without `LONGTEXT` column, it works fine:

```
insert into local_table (id)
select id from remote_table@ccs
```

And when I try to copy `LONGTEXT` column - I get `ORA-00997`:

```
insert into local_table (id, long_content) 
select id, long_content from remote_table@ccs
```

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

I've tried copying this table using CTAS:

```
create table local_temp_table as
select *
from remote_table@ccs
```

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Using update on already copied rows:

```
update local_table lt
set lt.long_content = (
    select rt.long_content
    from remote_table@ccs rt
    where rt.id = lt.id
)
```

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Using dynamic sql:

```
execute immediate 'insert into local_table (long_content) select long_content from remote_table@ccs where id = 1';
```

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Same error appears when I try to copy table with `LONGBLOB` column.

At this point I'm not sure what causes the problem - my setup, or my approach to copy table in PL/SQL.

Comment: Oracle is seeing the source column as a LONG, which presents fiendishly difficult challenges when attempting anything useful with them. I also have add issue with CLOBs going from Oracle to MariaDB via ODBC Connect. Our solution was to split the CLOBs into VARCHAR2(2000) columns, receive these into MariaDB and join them up again. Convoluted, clunky. Alternative is to use a Java/Python program to copy the data.

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one who have troubles dealing with LOBs over DB links. I went with python script to copy tables with LOB columns.